# StreamReader - url, ReadToEnd

Tags: c#

I need a little help. I have a file on my website, and i need to read this file in my program, do something and after that.. i need to read another line, so i need a "while".. etc. The "while" or something like that, have to read first line, after that the second line, etc.

Here is example what i need to do:

I have a text:

```
Something1
Something2
Something3
Something4
```

ok and i need for first read the first line.. do something.. and after that.. read the second line(Something2).. do something.. and after that read the third line.. to end. I have this  code:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
        System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead("http://example.com/subdom/prg/text.txt");

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {
            do 
            {
                String text = reader.ReadLine();
                SendLogin(text, "password", "1"); 
            }while(false);
        }
```

I didn't have any problem with file on my desktop, etc.. but with website i don't know how to solve this problem. :/

I had this before:

```
using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"login-mails.txt"))
            {

            while (!Reader.EndOfStream)
                {

                    string reader = Reader.ReadLine();
                    SendLogin(reader, "password", "1"); 



                }

            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `while(false);` wont iterate at all. also where is your problem. i dont see question.

Comment: If i will use the "false".. the cycle will read ALL things at one time.. i need to read first thing.. do something.. and after that read the second thing, etc.

Comment: It's a login on website.. i don't want to read all the text at the one time.. if i will do it.. it'll be something like that "Something1Something2Something3"

Comment: i think your problem is enter char. try this `SendLogin(reader + "\n", "password", "1");`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because of the `while(false)` statement. It will read one line and then get to this statement and exit.

Something like this will work:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead("http://example.com/subdom/prg/text.txt");

using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
    {
        string text = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WEE07N)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var web = new WebClient())
using (var stream = web.OpenRead("http://example.com/subdom/prg/text.txt"))  
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line = null;
    while ( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        SendLogin(line, "password", "1");
    }
}
```

For fun, you can abstract this into a re-usable method:

```
public void ForEachLine(string url, Action<string> oneline)
{
    using (var web = new WebClient())
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(web.OpenRead(url)))
    {
        string line = null
        while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           oneline(line);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
ForEachLine("http://example.com/subdom/prg/text.txt", 
       l =>  SendLogin(l, "password", "1")
);
```